# Auto add Images to entry after ftp to server

Tags: image, how-to

I have a potential client (car dealership) where in their existing 12 year old site they daily upload an Excel file to add/update/delete vehicles in stock. One file for new vehicles and one for used.

However the excel file does not have a column for images and they are unwilling/unable to add one. Instead they want images to be added in the same way they currently are.

All images are ftp'd up to the server and are named ##_stocknumber so 01_12345, 02_12345, 03_12345 would be attached to the same entry but 01_4455, 02_4455, 03_4455, 04_4455 would be attached to a different entry. After upload the go to a link that processes the images and then emails any stock numbers that are missing images.

Is there some way that this can be achieved in ExpressionEngine?

Comment: Would this be better asked at http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: edited out "craft" I actually posted in both craft and EE as I'm looking for this functionality but doesn't seem to exist that I'm aware of.

Comment: dunno if there's a hook in EE, but a cron that triggers that hook would be the way for me

Answer (score 0):

As the number of files (IMG) will never be known you are always going to be fighting a losing battle.

However, if you are aware of the max number of img per entry and you have the unique identifier already in the entry you could just do a hardcoded list like

```
<img src="01-{field-with-id}>
<img src="02-{field-with-id}">
<img src="03-{field-with-id}">
```

This may produce unwanted results but with no way of knowing how many images to expect in the parent entry you're going to have, your hands are tied.

Even if you were able to sync the images into EE, it would be for naught as your entries have NFI that they exist.

Your client has to be willing to tweak the source info, even if it's just a total number of images - this is not a limit of the CMS it's a limit of info supplied.